# Select within a select based on results MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table e.g.

```
Artist     Title      Song Key
A          Title A    A
A          Title A    B
A          Title A    F
B          Title B    A
```

I want to return each individual song but also show how many versions there are of that song e.g. Ideal results would be:

```
Artist     Title       How_many
A          Title A     3
B          Title B     1
```

This is what I'm trying but the count counts all tracks and not just from the current line:

```
SELECT *, 
       ( select count(*) 
           from tracks 
          where artist=artist 
            AND title=title ) as How_many 
  from tracks
 where easytosing='Yes'
 group by title, artist
 order by track_id desc
```

Is this possible using a  nested query or is there a better way?

Comment: Do you want to count how many tracks are "easy to sing" in every artist-title? Or all the tracks?

Comment: @ypercube Ideally, all the tracks - e.g. if there are 4 which have same title and artist, but only two easytosing, i'd like the count to be 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT Artist,Title, COUNT(*) FROM TABLE1 GROUP BY Artist,Title
```

**[SAMPLE FIDDLE](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/25666/1)**

Comment: This answer is very similar to Akam's but is grouped by Title as well as Artist, which is what the question asked for.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
SELECT Artist, title, count(*) as How_many 
FROM tracks
WHERE easytosing='Yes'
GROUP BY Artist,Title
```

Comment: `title` is within your select statement, must add it to the `group by` clause

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT t.*, how_many
        from tracks t
inner join 
( select title,artist, count(*)  ,how_many
           from tracks 
          group by artist,title ) as temp
temp.title=t.title and temp.artist=t.artist
 where easytosing='Yes'
```

Answer (score 0):

Just simply you can execute the following query with group by

```
  select Artist,Title,count(Song_Key) as How_many
  from Tracks
  group by Artist,Title
```

once you execute above query you will get the result as you like.

```
   ARTIST   TITLE   HOW_MANY
     A      Title A     3
     B      Title B     1
```

2 rows returned in 0.00 seconds

Answer (score -1):

In the specific case:

```
SELECT title, artist, count(*)
from tracks
where easytosing='Yes'
group by title, artist
```

because you get for every artist / title the number of songs.

You don't need of subquery in this case.

Another query you can perform is a query where the main select is based on disk table (I think you have a disk table where you have a foreign key at the artist and a name of your disk) where you get a number of contained song for each artist / disk.

In this way if there are no songs for one disk you get zero value.